# Horizontal Breadcrumb is not display properly in site Content and site setting page???

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have implement Horizontal Breadcrumb in my SharePoint site for that I have Some  modification in my custom master page
Below is my code for "BREADCRUMB"

```
<!-- Breadcrumb-->


 <div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox">
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
        <div id="breadcrumbnavigation">
             <span class="breadcrumb-nav"> 
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
                    <asp:SiteMapPath 
                    SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" 
                    id="ContentMap" 
                    SkipLinkText="" 
                    runat="server"
                    NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-sitemapdirectional"/>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </span>
        </div>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
 </div>
```

Test It work fine in all page in my Sharepointsite Except **SiteContent** and **Site Setting**  Page
you can notice from below snap
[image]

Thanks
SPS

Comment: Hi, I am stuck on same as above. Did u able to solve? If yes pls help me